# Remap keys with xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, remapping

Ubuntu 22.04 running inside MS Hyper-V.

I have used xmodmap to remap my left arrow key to right Control key.
The Left key is broken.

From xmodmap -pk , we can see 100 is Left key, and
109 is Control_R

```
keycode 100 = Left NoSymbol Left
keycode 101 =
keycode 102 = Right NoSymbol Right
keycode 103 = End NoSymbol End
keycode 104 = Down NoSymbol Down
keycode 105 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 106 = Insert NoSymbol Insert
keycode 107 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
keycode 108 = KP_Enter NoSymbol KP_Enter
keycode 109 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
```

so I have changed 109 to this,  "keycode 109 = Left NoSymbol Left"

here is how I did this,

xmodmap -pk > .Xmodmap, then did above change.
then xmodmap .Xmodmap

The Control_R key remapped to Left key, and it worked, but there is one issue.

To make cursor goes left, I have to press down Ctr_R and release Ctr_R and repeat this pattern.

I could not just press down  Ctr_R to make cursor goes left.